# Tensorflow: Using tf.slice to split the input

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to split my input layer into different sized parts. I'm trying to use tf.slice to do that but it's not working.

Some sample code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

ph = tf.placeholder(shape=[None,3], dtype=tf.int32)

x = tf.slice(ph, [0, 0], [3, 2])

input_ = np.array([[1,2,3],
                   [3,4,5],
                   [5,6,7]])

with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
        print sess.run(x, feed_dict={ph: input_})
```

Output:

```
[[1 2]
 [3 4]
 [5 6]]
```

This works and is roughly what I want to happen, but I have to specify the first dimension (`3` in this case). I can't know though how many vectors I'll be inputting, that's why I'm using a `placeholder` with `None` in the first place!

Is it possible to use `slice` in such a way that it will work when a dimension is unknown until runtime?

I've tried using a `placeholder` that takes its value from `ph.get_shape()[0]` like so: `x = tf.slice(ph, [0, 0], [num_input, 2])`. but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can specify one negative dimension in the `size` parameter of `tf.slice`. The negative dimension tells Tensorflow to dynamically determine the right value basing its decision on the other dimensions.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

ph = tf.placeholder(shape=[None,3], dtype=tf.int32)

# look the -1 in the first position
x = tf.slice(ph, [0, 0], [-1, 2])

input_ = np.array([[1,2,3],
                   [3,4,5],
                   [5,6,7]])

with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
        print(sess.run(x, feed_dict={ph: input_}))
```

Comment: Nice. Thank you! Strange though that they use inconsistent notation (`None` for placeholders and negative for this).

Comment: @nessuno print at the end has missing bracket, cannot add fix, because stackoverflow requires at least 6 characters for the update.

Answer (score 5):

For me, I tried another example to let me understand the slice function

```
input = [
    [[11, 12, 13], [14, 15, 16]],
    [[21, 22, 23], [24, 25, 26]],
    [[31, 32, 33], [34, 35, 36]],
    [[41, 42, 43], [44, 45, 46]],
    [[51, 52, 53], [54, 55, 56]],
    ]
s1 = tf.slice(input, [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 3])
s2 = tf.slice(input, [2, 0, 0], [3, 1, 2])
s3 = tf.slice(input, [0, 0, 1], [4, 1, 1])
s4 = tf.slice(input, [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1])
s5 = tf.slice(input, [2, 0, 2], [-1, -1, -1]) # negative value means the function cutting tersors automatically
tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as s:
    print s.run(s1)
    print s.run(s2)
    print s.run(s3)
    print s.run(s4)
```

It outputs:

```
[[[21 22 23]]]

[[[31 32]]
 [[41 42]]
 [[51 52]]]

[[[12]]
 [[22]]
 [[32]]
 [[42]]]

[]

[[[33]
  [36]]
 [[43]
  [46]]
 [[53]
  [56]]]
```

The parameter begin indicates which element you are going to start to cut.
The size parameter means how many element you want on that dimension.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try out this one

`x = tf.slice(ph, [0,0], [3, 2])`

As your starting point is `(0,0)` second argument is `[0,0]`.
You want to slice three raw and two column so your third argument is `[3,2]`.

This will give you desired output.