# Select or slice tensor by a tensor array of random indices?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, slice

I'm trying to replicate this in TensorFlow:

```
mat = np.matrix("1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9")
matrix([[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]])
mat[2]
matrix([[7, 8, 9]])
```

I get this error:

> ```
> X_batch = X_train[batch]
> ```
>
> IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

`X_train` is `batch_size x (other dimensions)` and `batch` is a 1-d tensor of random values.

I'm trying to take a random batch from a training set (really I'm trying to figure out how to train for multiple epochs, [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48977277/1339987)) and thought a random tensor of indices is the way to go, but this isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer from this similar question: [Tensorflow: Using tf.slice to split the input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39054414/tensorflow-using-tf-slice-to-split-the-input)

The answer seems to be [tf.gather](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather) which does exactly this.